# fscanf returning random large numbers

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read what is actually an image file, but already converted into a .txt file as follows. The structure "image" is already defined. The code is as follows.

```
image read_Buffer(char* filename)//read from file in "buffer format" i.e 1 pixel at a time.
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r+");//input.txt is the image file
    image img;
    fscanf(file,"%d\t", &img.height);
    fscanf(file,"%d\n", &img.breadth);//First line of "input.txt" gives the image dimensions
    img.size = img.height*img.breadth;
    img.value = (int*) malloc(img.size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i<img.size; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d\n", &img.value[i]);
    }
    free(img.value);
    fclose(file);
    return img;
}
```

The image dimensions are in the first line, and img.height and img. breadth read successfully. However, the problem is that img.value[0] and img.value[1] both seem to be large integers. From then img.value[2] to the end of the file, everything reads successfully.

For reference is the first few lines of input.txt:

```
69  97
168
166
122
126
138
127
125
122
123
129
119
105
106
120
125
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `fscanf()`.

You shouldn't be freeing `img.value` before returning `img`.

Your current code returns `img` that contains a [dangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) `value` pointer, dereferencing which results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

P.S. You do need to make sure that you free `img.value` eventually, after you're done with it. Otherwise you'd have a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Yes, you're spot on - I moved free(img.value) to much later in the program, after all operations on img, and that works exactly as it should. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3141961: Pleasure!